# we have integration b\w SAP to salesforce without using middleware and also without using credentials?

Tags: integration, wsdl, custom

what i doing now is, i have written custom webservice and gave to sap team. we are planning connect salesforce system using  SSL certificate for mutual authentication.

my question is how to pass the certificate parameter with in custom webservices?
because they do not want use login credentials and other thing is SAP side there is no option to parse our WSDL.

so how to handshake our system through CUSTOM WSDL?